# How can I make a native linux app executable in linux as part of JPackage installation

Tags: java, linux, java-14, jpackage

I am packaging a Java application (called Jaikoz) using **JPackage** (Java 14) for linux.

The java application has to sometimes call a c program called **fpcalc64**, on installation it gets stored in the **app** folder, but it only has **rw** permission

**Question 1**

Is there a way I can give it execute permission as part of install ?

**Question 2**

Even if I manually go into the app folder and use `chmod 777 fpcalc64` to give full execute permission, it still doesn't run and my Java program complains it doesn't have permission, this continues to happen even if I restart the application, how can this be ?

e.g

Fails

```
Jul 4, 2020 11:17:46 AM: WARNING: Unable to retrieve an acoustic id for song 2 file /home/ubuntu/Downloads/RedSharp_-_Walk_in_the_row.mp3 because Cannot run program "/home/ubuntu/code/jthink/jaikoz/JaikozAppImage/jaikoz/lib/app/fpcalc64": error=13, Permission denied
```

But if I run from linux shell it works

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/code/jthink/jaikoz/JaikozAppImage/jaikoz/lib/app$ ls -l fpcalc*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 ubuntu ubuntu 2210876 Jul  4 11:15 fpcalc
-rwxrwxrwx 1 ubuntu ubuntu 2249272 Jul  4 11:15 fpcalc64
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/code/jthink/jaikoz/JaikozAppImage/jaikoz/lib/app$ ./fpcalc64 /home/ubuntu/Downloads/Red*
FILE=/home/ubuntu/Downloads/RedSharp_-_Walk_in_the_row.mp3
DURATION=273
FINGERPRINT=AQADtIsURmsSDc9i44-Iqsemr8a1MIOXKBHCi9CJ0M7R-MH5oNNy_Dp26ag55EmUJ5DjI-zREE-P9wz-odeKCyGbHXriIj8qbiYaPRue4_zx7MHHE1eiw1yE80d1IdmDnDy-LCeub_gVVLkGP8uHmTNhVjkicUeyh0MTHs_RE8-Jurg7XItwHVl-aFmHPGMq_Al-NCGFx0d6adD6I39RnQoaTXmK48JhTqOM58R19LED8yBf9LvQo1GW4viRk4Qm6cUvpHlRi8dn9MngFqRy-EdGlNPxHbp8oR8aLnvBLkb_4I8KS9Kh57jEKsOv4nD04UeZmZDyC64efLB1jK8Oj8hP-BSuF7aQ92h-4h1eKJJ1wYErregFzTWaH_m14Q--o9nsEe47Ij_EG33GI8e14xQf1Eifo5Z03IeeK2C0ODGaD6xl5Kh9OD68HdfwhuiPH33x9kg7HdpRuQgjnbiOe8Sn0EJt-AsR6sVxPQr65vg0aM8KjeTB5Hi4RviLJqYI7QoqsTApR4PPJwi_9LiHJmWCfmiyODWYX0OTLzfCB1c-4UQf6Dj0p3gH7xH8o8-Ja4rxoz--CHpy-EWPH_2h5dODUoaWmDmeo4ko5UKbzQquNJmGypnRfIEmkUEeRcZzVNwSBv3RsBo4dUZu6HKHrgkk-aiVPUR-vNJQ-WgYx-ija7hGZCc0_ngQ6gt8432Cpk6Fp0dzIjx03AjThOGO5lfwLMWF9MIX5Qp0NFn04w5vNFUufNGhpWJcPIrR4CS-5RHK_9BSDXcIPyZ-HOdBv3hQbjKafxA8adXw49OFPEWjFrWy42FD9Irh6sgrodEuPG0CmclSXNA6wmMGbb3QTTwa8cGDPoPHHddycXijBdKNvGD-4CyRb8F3wV-c4LXBKxHywNlB9kf3C7YeNHQCcsaJ_IOWPZEQHz-e6DhFnFFwIvyhE2ePfDnyY8pz6IJ1uMoO7WGIp8fXM9gqpsITdNnRkDu0RYdjPcHHoMl_qL4F9gjDMSUOKj8YTlF8NDtRoeqGpjv4MwiTN4WG-OFhTUuMVUly9FHRcD3wHTl0ZUO46miyfcFz1Dr8HLYZtMtxS0P4Q26OfBpcFd-xySx64gadHWF2QeYxHb8SCuWSHV6iS3gG44fHoM0wLzqa8NvxV3ihmUeuXLiUXeiF5iCPlzijWEIiqk-QH490PDnqo3mOv-Dk44qMTyEajauCqyfCvNAzNOPRL7hyQs3AH8e-ZBx6K_CPib3AaMrRKMePoel79Ieu4seXD0-uQI_RrDOGcsFz_CG-Q6OPs4fxHY90KNdKuOqPThX2x2jqoFV2BXK0R9Cpw8-KnIyPH48O7ngySujbJPAyFln4Qz-meCtKXSPy4zq6oqlyfDu-6MFNo3kQXtARcXvw4Dn6rQkY5ccVBv5wSTVyXKIOPVEOLUm_oC_2aGhqtAuaS0XZQ-ml4dC_4x_6TEO-qPBuHFRSHWEfmTjyb2ge9PEwnDhznEeYZw4OHdEzo8-L97gSXPLxojn7IKShbw_KHmEaBedBeifK4_sRppK64HkLXXnwHc0JbT8eqUT84OTxobKI9chv6PAe1CqDXEEppceRE1Oh6wquD_mM__B5ZGfx5YSu1OjRaH_QC9cOmWkBVzNYhkG1FxXFB155pE7wE39wTkmPSqeGI48P7UWqLqh19EfzlAS_408RXvDRHjpx4X6CHrkTGF15PEd2PUOrPPBxirg147tQlcepoz-a57gYEXqO3oOZN1AdPNMRWsePatsxRUd05oLuEz--En-HNq4Cxy0xrUflHmKVY3eh5Tl-_EPtUAg3H3m1GB3roWEkgQ9raOFHhA_hE99w6qjFw9pmdC06Ssh9MN3xB-mk4sLZTkV5mJPg6UevNjhlXLrQIFTUqZDyIf3xo77wpWiFO0HzCz_y458CPcOPhmCeDJcfPDjaw1aOE99YOCf0Hb-KJ6oAXTLxIz6u5YJvF33RH3ZytMgP6D_aa_iF_RE2hzCjKAFO9mj2GMc7Bs-O_6FwC02g9Qf35Xge4kPeG0ye43mCWjROvEa8Cc2Xoudx5Ceeo-Ee_PgjtfAT_Pjg_sgH-Q_C_MS9FGel4fjAMqimg8n649uDnEH1QfnhaUerHFeP_hGa88iF_sfV4WQ1nMfWC0dKp9BDNF9oPMFx_dDuIb3wk_CFtyZRXA7-4NNBTpa0IMweyEc-pnCVHJ8eWDum48sPxMWe51C9GY2eDvuFh1kCOdmxK4zQR-gPP8YZWjDXeNCXzLDmHNUjHFS-4hp-4moQi3yOU0IfNLJyXNJl9Dya7PmGf0d2aMdD9UhDJTpOYdyyoLrw40yOPCJ0lkH1G34t6MyPNEsiXSi1WegrWDn6rXh49N8RrSIS6zt85uiNP_hBEz4xysJnhCp1XDo-VVJg5slw4D0q4Uoe_KiuFL6CHipd5AmLRw-aL3GKacGRJzqSO3FwJi9-4c6Ekzm2G5eOW7GQK8pHNLF0dMWVQ2wm44FGIgxfvBSeJ8N9TAmp4LngXngraUGkLJAb9EOjkfg-4nF8bHqg8wKeHFf2oPqD5j_UDz_eLMV1fLlRwyPRZyyU7_jwREaYaWjH42WTEI2-ok6KXFGIH-KY-PiO64fOo3uQxtHhSaSIp0_gE0e6EhV1QldyGfl8-ErxCx-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
```

**Question 3**

Do I have to store fpcalc64 in the **bin** folder rather than **lib/app**. If I do how do I do that, it is a precompiled binary ?

Comment: Please add the code that invokes the C program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution (something I had hit before).

Since Java 9 when you call an external app with Java on linux is uses `lib/jspawnhelper` to decide how to run the application. Because I provided  linux runtime but the runtime was built on Windows when it was checked into source control it had lost any execute permissions. Therefore when my application complained about permissions it was actually complaining about permissions on jspawnhelper.

I also found that if you do set the permissions they will be respected when you build the package. I didn't realize this because previosly I was building linux installer on Windows and had to add extra commands to Izpack installer to make them executable.

So in summary the solution was to set execute permissions on jspawnhelper and fpcalc and commit to source control, then `Jpackage` would work.